# Windows service - System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly my.dll

Tags: service

I created Net 4.5 Windows service which is used my.dll. My.dll is compiled  with CLR support. I created msi file using Project Setup project from Visual Studio 2013. I set `vsdraCOM` option for my.dll file to provide auto registering of library.

When I install and start service under development machine (with Visual studio 2013) using `sc` command the service starts well. But then I use msi file for installing under "clear" machine and then try to start I get an error: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly my.dll`

I tried to register dll by hand using regsvr32 my.dll but got an error: Could not load module "\mydll". Could not find path .` (the error message was translated from my native language).

I also used ProcMon to analyze what was the problem but didn't see any faults.

I tried to put dll file into System32 directory but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed redistributable package and add the following dlls in System32 directory: msvcp120d.dll, msvcr120d.dll, vccorlib120d.dll from c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\x64\Microsoft.VC120.DebugCRT\

The problem is solved